# how do remove underline in side-menu ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic2, side-menu

I've create a side menu.
and button inside it

```
<ion-content style="background-image: url(assets/imgs/background.jpg)" >
<div id="sideBody">
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose  ion-item *ngFor="let p of Func.getPages()" (click)="openPage(p, p.title)">
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

how to make underline inside menu not showing and how change color text menu?

Comment: I suggest you are inspect the element in your browsers devtool, alsmost every browser has one these days. for example chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: what style you give in id=sideBody ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <button menuClose  ion-item *ngFor="let p of Func.getPages()" (click)="openPage(p, p.title)">
      {{p.title}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Simply by putting no-lines property in  like above i had edited your code.