# Icon in side menu has underline/Too big?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I made a side menu with icons and added an active class to change the colour of the selected page.

All is working fine, its just that on iOS and android there is this black underline or the icon is a little too big. I am new to ionic and am learning on the go, but this small issue is annoying me. I think i am going to make the icon a tiny bit smaller on iOS and android for it to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here you can see the Issue i am talking about.
[image]

**App.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [color]="p.color">
    <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" ></ion-icon>
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
openPage(page) {
// close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
this.menu.close();
// navigate to the new page if it is not the current page 
this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
// Color for the active item
page.color='dark';

for (let p of this.pages) {

  if(p.title==page.title){
    p.color='dark';
  }else{
    p.color='';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Well i found an answer to my own question, i should have done a little more research before asking the question.

All i had to do was to add the "no-lines" property in the ion-list tag.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list no-lines>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [color]="p.color">
    <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" ></ion-icon>
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

[how do remove underline in side-menu ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770341/how-do-remove-underline-in-side-menu-ionic-2)